# PHP imagecropauto заменяет прозрачный фон на чёрный

Tags: php, png

На входе PNG с прозрачным фоном. Когда начинаю обрезать края, всё что не обрезано (на фото сложная фигура с кривыми краями) заливается чёрным фоном. Как это поправить?

```
$sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($filename))

imagealphablending($sourceImage, false);
imagesavealpha($sourceImage, true);

$backgroundColor = imagecolorat($sourceImage, 1, 1);
$crop = imagecropauto($sourceImage, IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD, 0.5, $backgroundColor);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($crop);
imagedestroy($crop);
```

PHP Version 7.0.18

Comment: вам нужно использовать цвет с альфа-каналом для бэкграунда http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php

Comment: а еще лучше взять [imagine/imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) или аналог

Comment: На входе файл с прозрачным фоном, т.е. уже с альфаканалом. Я пытался его дополнительно вручную ещё раз применить к результату кропа, но почему-то всё равно фон чёрный остаётся. Если не кропаю, а только ресайз например делаю, то прозрачность не пропадает

Comment: этот эффект вероятнее всего получается из-за цвета бэкграунда, и я не могу гарантировать, что вывод imagecolorat содержит альфа-канал в прафильных битах

Comment: `imagealphablending($sourceImage, false);` => `imagealphablending($sourceImage, true);` ?